# The code does not work in FF and IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(window).on('scroll.toElement', function (e) {
    var s_top = $("body").scrollTop();
    var el = $("#popular").offset().top;
    if(s_top > el){
        console.log('Test')
        $(window).off('scroll.toElement');
    }
});
```

The chrome and opera works in FF and IE does not work. How to solve the problem, tell me?
I need that function `console.log()` worked only 1 time with the achievement of the desired block. The two browsers that I wrote everything is OK, in the other two - is not working. And I can not understand why.
[example](https://jsfiddle.net/b2cag72w/)

Comment: In general I don't see a problem here. It could belong to come strange css. Can you create a (not) working example here or on jsfiddle?

Comment: why don't you use simply `$(window).on('scroll', function() {`?

Comment: Would this make any difference? @vijayP

Comment: i think so @eisbehr...

Comment: `$("body").scrollTop()` is maybe the issue. Not sure it is scrollable element in all browser, using `window` should fix it i guess. In you case, test using: `var s_top = $(this).scrollTop()`

Comment: Why? `.toElement` is just a jQuery namespace. @vijayP

Comment: @vijayP How that? OP is already using it, just namespaced

Comment: `does not work` - *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers* - does not work does not cut it

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
Replaced 
`var s_top = $("body").scrollTop();` on `var s_top = $(window).scrollTop();`

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/b2cag72w/1/)